# how to put the time in a textbox and save it in a var on c#

Tags: c#, time

I'm developing something like  an diary of activities. the current problem is when the user needs to put the hour in a textbox whit this format 00:00 but
i don't know how to save that information in a var. i tried with a maskedthextbox but doesnt work, now i found a method called 'datetime' it works but the problem its like i only need the time, i dont care the date i just wanna save the hour like the user put into the textbox. Ex: if the user says like  the first activity starts at 08:00 he gonna put 08:00 into a textbox and that information needs to be saved in a variable datetime i think, im not sure about what kind of variable i need to use to do that. Please if someone can help me.

edit: im using visual studio 15.Iim working on windows forms
 this is the code of the problem:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
           Im working with a datagridview control for the days of the week
           in the code im only testing the code with one day
        */

        checkedListBox1.Visible = false;
        comboBox1.Enabled = false;
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        DateTime hi = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox3.Text);


        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value =   this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(hi);
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView3.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView4.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView5.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView6.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to get a datetime to display only the hours you can use DateTime.ToString("HH:mm")

Comment: Can you post code and result?

Comment: Whats' the technoology? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET...